# Predicate in RavenDB dynamic query not working correctly

Tags: ravendb

Consider the 2 queries:

```
   var test1 = store.OpenSession().Query<TestClass>().Where(x => x.Id == 1).ToList();
   var test2 = store.OpenSession().Query<TestClass>().Where(x => x.Id >= 1).ToList();
```

test1 returns 1 item in the list.
test2 returns 0 items.

For some reason I can't get it to return any items in the 2nd query.
Is there any reason for this?

Comment: It's either a bug or unsupported. I've created a failing test and I'll send it through to ayende for comment.

Comment: See https://github.com/csainty/ravendb/commit/c8b376f159331ba67a18cccfb2d8345fee427660 for the test Chris is referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so as commented I created a failing test for this and sent it through to ayende for comment.

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/issues/337

The answer is that it was not currently supported, but ayende has made some changes to support it.

https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/commit/f6beb4f9d8c763c3eb37f93fed84c657e0f207fb

Though reading that commit comment, I am not sure he is happy about it :)

So if you need it now, you are going to have to go to source, otherwise it will make it into a future stable build.

Comment: OK thanks, I don't actually need the feature, I am currently just investigating the s/w.  If it isn't supported, why do they provide an entry point for predicate logic?

Comment: The problem is very specifically performing GreaterThan on the Id field. It's just not a usecase that makes much sense and therefore had not been considered previously. Id == x or OrderValue >= x are both ok.

Comment: Thanks, good to know I might have helped identify a bug in a great piece of s/w!